# Wait for a global variable to change its value

Tags: delphi

I have created following abstract code where the user has 2 buttons:

- One button is starting some kind of process. The global variable PleaseStop will tell the running process that it should stop its work.
- The other button sets the global variable `PleaseStop` which will tell the procedure to stop.

-

```
var
  PleaseStop: boolean;
  IsRunning: boolean;

procedure TForm1.RunActionClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  rnd: integer;
  tic: Cardinal;
begin
  try
    IsRunning := true;
    rnd := Random(100);
    while not PleaseStop do
    begin
      tic := GetTickCount;
      while (GetTickCount-tic < 1000) and not PleaseStop do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        Sleep(10);
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(rnd));
    end;
  finally
    IsRunning := false;
    PleaseStop := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.StopBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PleaseStop := true;
end;
```

Everything works as expected.

Now there will be problems if the user doesn't click the Stop button, but instead clicks the Run button again (which should be allowed).

I have now modified my code like this:

```
var
  PleaseStop: boolean;
  IsRunning: boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rnd: integer;
  tic: Cardinal;
begin
  // ---- BEGIN NEW ----
  if IsRunning then
  begin
    PleaseStop := true; // End the previous actions
    while PleaseStop do // Wait until the previous actions are done
    begin
      // TODO: this loop goes forever. PleaseStop will never become false
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Sleep(10);
    end;
    // Now we can continue
  end;
  // ---- END NEW ----

  try
    IsRunning := true;
    rnd := Random(100);
    while not PleaseStop do
    begin
      tic := GetTickCount;
      while (GetTickCount-tic < 1000) and not PleaseStop do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        Sleep(10);
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(rnd));
    end;
  finally
    IsRunning := false;
    PleaseStop := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PleaseStop := true;
end;
```

Clicking the Start button again will cause a deadlock.
I assume the compiler thinks that `while PleaseStop do` is equal to `while true do` since I just set `PleaseStop` to `true` earlier. But in fact, this variable should be monitored...

I also tried putting `[volatile]` in front of the variables, and make them member of TForm1, but that doesn't work either.

**Why didn't I use threads?**

- The code is heavily VCL dependent.
- The run button will start a dia show. Every time, the run button is clicked, a random picture folder will be chosen.
- So, when the user doesn't like the pictures, he will click "Run" again to switch to a new folder and start the new dia show automatically. The previous run should be stoppped therefore.

Comment: You can disable start button after process is started. `Button1.enabled := false;` or you can write thread- oriented code with critical sections and so on.

Comment: "_Now there will be problems if the user doesn't click the Stop button, but instead clicks the Run button again (**which should be allowed**)._" It's not enough to simply say "something should be allowed". The crucial _missing_ question is: ***what should happen?*** when the user clicks the run button again. 1) Queue a second run to start immediately after the first completes? 2) Perform the second Run concurrently with the first? 3) Ignore the second click? 4) Something else entirely? .... Also, if 1 or 2: Should there be a limit on the total  number of "Active Runs"?

Answer (score 4):

Your diagnosis is not exactly accurate, `ProcessMessages`, simply, cannot cause a previously retrieved message's processing to continue. You have to stop processing and let the execution continue from where re-entrancy occurred. Re-entrancy is the primary avoidance reason of `Application.ProcessMessages`, and you're doing it on purpose. Hard to work it out...

If you don't want to use synchronization and threading, you can use a timer instead. The code will be much simpler too.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Randomize;
end;

var
  rnd: Integer;

procedure TForm1.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  rnd := Random(100);
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.StopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(rnd));
end;
```

Comment: In the simplified example of printing a random number, this works, yes. But in my real code I do need to cleanup the running Timer1Timer() actions by sending the "stop signal" for various reasons. So, I have the same problem again: I am trying to stop and wait for the Timer1Time() code inside StartClick(), and this will cause a deadlock.

Comment: You can cleanup/setup if the timer is running. I can't imagine your deadlock situation, try to come up with an example.

Comment: The problem is basically the same (I think?): https://pastebin.com/NMp2X08L  . I'm afraid I didn't understand the problem with ProcessMessages

Comment: Get rid of your previous code; the loops and processmessages calls and all. A timer fires in specified intervals, use the ontimer event instead of the loop to run your code in periods. I don't think you will be able to duplicate your deadlock, but if you can then I'll understand.

Comment: The problem with Application.ProcessMessages is, you can't use it as a flow control tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your event handler like this:

```
var Needtorestart:Boolean = false;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   rnd: integer;
   tic: Cardinal;
begin
  // ---- BEGIN NEW ----
  if IsRunning then
  begin
    PleaseStop := true; // End the previous action
    Needtorestart := true;
    Exit;
    // Now we can continue
  end;
      // ---- END NEW ----

  try
    repeat
        IsRunning := true;
        rnd := Random(100);
        while not PleaseStop do
        begin
          Tic := GetTickCount;
          while (GetTickCount-tic < 1000) and not PleaseStop do
          begin
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            Sleep(10);
          end;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(rnd));
         end;
         PleaseStop := false;
    until not Needtorestart;
  finally
    IsRunning := false;
    PleaseStop := false;
    Needtorestart := false;
  end;
end;
```